# Multiple element name xml parsing

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse a xml file using Linq:

The XML structure seems to be all done via attributes instead of element names. Everything is an entry and I would like to get all the entries with a specific entry name e.g "data": example data below.

```
<entry name="data">
<entry name="001" description="Player LEFT">
  <entry name="001"  description="Player LEFT" type="richtext">Joe Bloggs</entry>
</entry>
<entry name="002" description="Team LEFT">
  <entry name="002"  description="Team LEFT" type="richtext">Stack Overflow</entry> 
</entry>
```

There could be 2 entries or 100 so I need to return everything under the "data" attribute in this case.

Currently what I have is:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\element1.xml");
var stuff = doc.Descendants("entry").Where(x => 
(string)x.Attribute("data") == "data").ToList();
```

I can get specific values but not the whole lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "specific values but not the whole lot"?  Can you give an example of what this is returning and what you want it to return?

Comment: Post sample XML that demonstrates how your current codes fails (in case currently posted XML doesn't). Indicates what you expect to get and what you actually got using that codes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a stab at this.  Does the following do what you want?

```
doc
.Descendants()
.Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "data")
.Descendants();
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! stabbing worked. I  added .Descendants().Elements("entry").ToList();  which gave me everything I want to parse into my own class. Cheers.